# Implementing access control in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, roles

I'm writing a role based application in ASP.NET MVC 3. Obviously, depending on the role the user is in, will depend what pages or functions they have access to.  I'm not really certain the best place, or way to implement this in an MVC application. Any information or points to certain resources would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to implement your own security and membership mechanism, or use something ready now?

Comment: I will probably be implementing my own via my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to implement your own membership system, then you can follow these steps:

1. Put an HttpModule (a class inheriting from IHttpModule) in the way of secure requests (requests you want to define access control for)
2. In that module, create a handler `AuthenticateRequest` event
3. In that handler, check the request for an **Authentication Cookie**. This cookie could be yours or you can use `FormsAuthentication` class to create, encrypt and decrypt cookies for you.
4. If cookie is present, then load the roles of the user, and store them in `HttpContext.Current.Items` as a key/value pair. This way, you can use it anywhere you want.
5. If not, then redirect the user to login page. The address of the login page could be retrieved from settings or web.config
6. In login page, get the login information of user including user name and password, then create an `Authentication Cookie` and send it to the client.

Answer (score 1):

The [Membership Provider](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/05/07/ASP.NET-2.0-Membership-and-Roles-Tutorial-Series.aspx) is built into .NET and can be used from MVC3.  The post I linked to is an overview how to use the default implementation that ships with the .NET framework,  it's possible to [create your own](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) but I suggest getting familiar with the default first.